# In MVC, does the View eventually render the HTML back to the Controller or does the view render the HTML to the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I usually see two graphs that illustrates the MVC architecture when I look it up on google: one being the View rendering HTML back to the browser directly and the other being the View rendering HTML back to the Controller and then the Controller renders the HTML to the browser.

Which is what is actually going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** HTML templates that are generated are fed back to the controller which is then sent back to the client (browser, API request endpoints).

In rails, controller is the point of contact of your application. Each request-response cycle between the client (browser or API endpoint) and the rails app (server) happens within a controller. The rails router delegates the controller and corresponding action to handle incoming request based on the configuration defined in `config/routes.rb` and get a response from the controller to send back to the requesting endpoint.

So, the controller takes the request, interacts with the model (if required), generates HTML template from the view file and sends it back to the requester.

[image: rails mvc diagram]

This is how it happens in rails MVC and probably works in similar fashion for other MVC frameworks as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Model**
Represents data.
It acts as an interface between the database and the application (as a data object).
It will handle validations, associations, transactions etc.

**Controller**
It gathers and processes data.
Handles code which does data selection and data messaging.

**View**
Displays output to the users
[reference](http://www.devcodenote.com/2015/04/mvc-model-view-controller.html)

From: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

> The model is the central component of the pattern. It expresses the application's behavior in terms of the problem domain, independent of the user interface.[6] It directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application.
>   A view can be any output representation of information, such as a chart or a diagram. Multiple views of the same information are possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view for accountants.
>   The third part, the controller, accepts input and converts it to commands for the model or view.[7]

So to answer your question the controller tells the view to update.